# ROS2 launch: No way to get log displayed in console?

Tags: ros2, ros2-launch

I'm using ROS2 humble under Windows. I have a very simple publisher and subscriber:

**Publisher:**

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

from sensor_msgs.msg import ChannelFloat32

class DummyPublisher(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('dummy_publisher')
        self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(ChannelFloat32, 'topic', 10)
        timer_period = 0.5  # seconds
        self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)
        self.i = 0

        self.t0 = self.get_clock().now().nanoseconds

    def timer_callback(self):
        msg = ChannelFloat32()
        msg.values = [ float((self.get_clock().now().nanoseconds-self.t0)/1e9), float(self.i), float(self.i*4) ]
        self.publisher_.publish(msg)
        self.get_logger().info('Publishing: "%s"\n' % str(msg.values))
        self.i += 1

def main(args=None):
    
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    publisher = DummyPublisher()

    rclpy.spin(publisher)

    # Destroy the node explicitly
    # (optional - otherwise it will be done automatically
    # when the garbage collector destroys the node object)
    publisher.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Subscriber:**

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

from sensor_msgs.msg import ChannelFloat32

class DummyListener(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('dummy_listener')
        self.subscription = self.create_subscription(
            ChannelFloat32,
            'topic',
            self.listener_callback,
            10)
        self.subscription  # prevent unused variable warning

    def listener_callback(self, msg):
        self.get_logger().info('I heard: "%s"' % str(msg.values))

def main(args=None):
    
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    listener = DummyListener()

    rclpy.spin(listener)

    # Destroy the node explicitly
    # (optional - otherwise it will be done automatically
    # when the garbage collector destroys the node object)
    listener.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I execute them from different consoles, running:

```
ros2 run my_package talker
ros2 run my_package listener
```

It just works fine, I see the outputs in the console, one being, for instance, `[INFO] [1696599163.297177500] [dummy_publisher]: Publishing: "array('f', [9.007436752319336, 17.0, 68.0])"` the other one `[INFO] [1696599163.298260700] [dummy_listener]: I heard: "array('f', [9.007436752319336, 17.0, 68.0])"`.

However, when I use a launch script:

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
import launch_ros.actions

def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='my_package', executable='talker'),
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='my_package', executable='listener'),
    ])
```

The console does not log messages anymore:

```
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below C:\Users\XXXXXX\.ros\log\2023-10-06-15-36-12-882760-XXXXXXXXX-26924
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [talker.EXE-1]: process started with pid [8252]
[INFO] [listener.EXE-2]: process started with pid [10256]
```

I tried to add `output='screen'` and even `output='screen', emulate_tty=True, arguments=[('__log_level:=debug')]` as I saw some posts proposing this as a solution but it did not change anything.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there no way to have the log be displayed?